# Why does body min-width not work alongside fixed divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a JSfiddle with the code to my problem:
[https://jsfiddle.net/367v2n1q/14/](https://jsfiddle.net/367v2n1q/7/)

On the right you will see a red bar which has a fixed position. I'm trying to get the body to have a min width of 808 pixels, but it is letting me re-size the body to smaller than 808.

The center div stops shrinking when it hits 808 pixels wide, but then the fixed div on the right keeps on going and envelops the rest of the content.

CSS

```
body.total{
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 808px;
}
.rightSidePane {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    clear: both;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

HTML snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- head stuff here -->
    </head>
<body class="total">
        <div id="wrapper" class="leftSidePane">

            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                    <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">

<div class="mainContent">
    <h1>
        WWW.SITE.COM
    </h1>
    <h2>dedicated to stuff</h2>
    <p style="text-align: center;
    color: #5D5D5D;">last updated: 01.01.2016</p>
    <br>
    <p style="
       font-family: 'Times New Roman';
       color: #C1C1C1;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-size: 20px;
       text-align: center;
       ">Site visited 27 times</p>
    <br><br>
    <hr>
</div>
</div>
<div class="rightSidePane">

    <!-- Side bar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand-right">
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="barfix"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="board">
            </li>
            <li class="nextBar">
            </li>
            <li>
    <div class="tileRightInit" id="bs">
        <div class="barTextRight">MAIN</div>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="tileRight" id="bs">
        <div class="barTextRight">News</div>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="tileRight" id="bs">
        <div class="barTextRight">Links</div>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="tileRight" id="bs">
        <div class="barTextRight">Credits</div>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="tileRight" id="bs">
        <div class="barTextRight">About</div>
    </div>
</li>

            <li class="bottomRight">
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `body` element never goes below 808px width. And you even see a horizontal scroll bar appear.

Comment: Your right, it doesn't. I don't understand what is happening, is the body moving to the right off the page?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I needed to be using absolute positioning for the div on the right. Here is the fixed JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/367v2n1q/15/

Here is the fixed CSS:

```
body.total{
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 840px;
}
.rightSidePane {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    clear: both;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

The HTML remained the same. Thanks @Roope for pointing out that the body never fell below 808px width, I don't know why I didn't catch that but you pointed me in the right direction.